# Проблемы с терминалом mac

Tags: python, django, консоль, pip

В терминале у меня zsh shell, bash вообще ни на одну команду не реагирует, а через какое то время пишет "Процесс завершен" и там и там нет домика слева от слева "Терминал" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще изначально я хотел установить Django, но как матрешка у меня начали появляться проблема за проблемой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также у меня когда я прописываю python --version, показывает что у меня версия 2.7.10
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя у меня установлена на mac последняя версия python[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Друзья, буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: pip3 install Django

Answer (score 1):

- Версия питона 3-го проверяется такой командой `python3 --version`
- `pip` команда так же меняется на `pip3`

Answer (score 1):

1. Перезагрузи компьютер
2. Вместо `pip` используй `pip3`